# JavaFX: Css o Clase

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-css

Quisiera tener algo de orientación acerca del CSS de JavaFX, la cuestión/problema es el siguiente:

Estoy intentando crear el efecto `Hover` en un ImageView el cuál inicia con una **opacidad de 0.5**; la cuestión es que cree una Hoja de Estilo la cual llame `Efectos.css` en la que tengo dicho código que hace el efecto (subo un screenshot para ser más claro). El caso es que utilizó el comando `btn_cerrar.getStyleClass().add("imageview");` pero no crea ningún efecto.

**Efectos.css:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte, tenía pensado dejar el CSS y hacer dicho efecto con código (JavaFX) en donde creo el siguiente código:

**Esto está creado en el FXMLController:**

```
@FXML
private void efectosMouse(MouseEvent event){

    btn_cerrar.setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent event1) -> {
        btn_cerrar.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1");
    });

    btn_cerrar.setOnMouseExited((MouseEvent event1) -> {
        btn_cerrar.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 0.5");
    });   
}
```

El problema es que este mismo código lo re-utilizaré en otros elementos de tipo ImageView, a lo cual, no quiero repetir estás líneas durante todo el código de mi programa. ¿Es posible crear este código en una clase e ir acudiendo al dicha clase cuando la necesite?

**IDE's:**

- Netbeans.
- SceneBuilder 2.0.

**PD:** Espero ser claro con mis dudas, de antemano agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: La mejor forma de proceder es la 1ª, tener una hoja de estilo y aplicar los estilos usando nombres de clases, ids, etc. Quizá no esté funcionando porque `Efectos.css` no se está cargando bien. Debes verificar que se cargue correctamente usando la ruta correcta. **[Como dice la documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)**, las hojas de estilo deben cargarse en la escena. Algo así: `Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 400);
scene.getStylesheets().add("rutacorrecta/Efectos.css");`

Comment: Puedes agregar la hoja de estilo también desde Scene Builder, **[ver este tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part4/)**

Comment: Hola, buenas noches, hombre gracias, me hiciste caer en cuenta en lo de cargar la hoja de estilo, se me había olvidado hacerlo, ahora y encontré la solución, de verdad muchas gracias, fue un error de mi parte, gracias. Ya todo funciona a la perfección de nuevo gracias. :D

Comment: Si quieres escribiré una respuesta que quede de referencia para futuros usuarios. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Comment: Si, estaría bien, gracias. saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mejor forma de proceder es la 1ª, es decir, tener una hoja de estilo y aplicar los estilos usando nombres de clases, ids, etc. De esa forma hay más flexibilidad en el código, es más fácil de mantener o de actualizar que si escribes los estilos directamente en cada elemento.

Quizá no esté funcionando porque `Efectos.css` no se está cargando bien. Debes verificar que se cargue correctamente usando la ruta correcta. [Como dice la documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm), las hojas de estilo deben cargarse por lo general en la escena. Algo así:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 400); 
scene.getStylesheets().add("rutacorrecta/Efectos.css");
```

Puedes agregar la hoja de estilo también desde Scene Builder, abriendo el archivo fxml al que le quieres aplicar el estilo, seleccionando el elemento root en la vista jerárquica de Scene Builder y luego en propiedades. [Lo puedes ver explicado con imágenes aquí](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part4/).